# No result in searching specific lines in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Im trying to select from Get-Service command all the lines with string "Running" and it doesnt give results

My command for it is :

`Get-Service | Select-String -Pattern "Running"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Service` returns **objects** with properties like `Status`.
This is not a set of textlines to use Select-String on..

Instead, use `Where-Object` to filter out the objects with status 'Running':

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Running'}
```